# Pandas filter dataframe to show only rows which contain zeros

Tags: python, pandas

I have been looking for a while to, [show only rows which contain zeros and also way to show rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2erRk.png) without zeros. The problem is i have a lot of columns and i want to be able to apply this method to all columns except column 'Result', without writing a list in hundred of names.

I am very puzzled with isnull() method because it just replaces all values with boolean values and looks rather useless to me.

P.S. could you please write a code to do the same operation but with infinite values. Inf in pandas dataframe.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use boolean index using combination of `loc` and `iloc` to select desired columns lets say you have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0,1,1], 'b':[0,1,0,1],'c':[1,1,2,1],'d':[4,1,6,1]})
df

    a   b   c   d
0   0   0   1   4
1   0   1   1   1
2   1   0   2   6
3   1   1   1   1
```

and you want to select all rows which have greater than zero values except `col a` then you can use this:

```
df.loc[(df.iloc[:,1:]!=0).all(1)]
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c   d
1   0   1   1   1
3   1   1   1   1
```

and when you want to discard all rows in `col a`with zeros valueand res as it is use:

```
df.loc[(df.iloc[:,:1]!=0).all(1)]
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c   d
2   1   0   2   6
3   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: happy to help, do upvote and accept the answer so that this can be closed

Answer (score 1):

For your sample data, as a "learning step" run:

```
df.drop(columns=['Result']).eq(0).any(axis=1)
```

The result will be a *Series* of *bool* type:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

containing answer to the question: Does **any** element in a row (*axis=1*)
== 0 (*eq(0)*) in a DataFrame without *Result* column (*drop(columns=['Result'])*)?

The above *Series* should be then used in a *boolean indexing*:

```
df[...]
```

So to get all rows **containing** any *0* (in columns other than *Result*), run:

```
df[df.drop(columns=['Result']).eq(0).any(axis=1)]
```

And to get rows **not** containing any *0* run:

```
df[~df.drop(columns=['Result']).eq(0).any(axis=1)]
```

Note that this solution works regardless of the position of *Result* column in
your DataFrame.